# Preview tags with docusign API

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the Rest API to create the docusign envelope. We have tags inside the document using anchor text. Is there a way to preview the tags before we send the envelope?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a way of mimicing the Preview feature when viewing envelopes through the DocuSign Console through the API, however the Embedded Sending functionality basically does a preview although you can change aspects about the envelope too.

With Embedded Sending you can generate a URL token that the sender can navigate to in an iFrame to view what's called the *Sender's View* or *Embedded Sending* view.  For security reasons every URL token that is generated is good for a one time use and expires after 5 mins.  If you need to preview more than once or you wait 5 mins without using then you just need to generate a new URL token, which is easy.

For more info on Embedding functionality, and Embedded Sending in particular, check out the API Walkthroughs:  http://iodocs.docusign.com/apiwalkthroughs In particular the bottom left walkthrough, [Embedded Sending](http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/embeddedSending) is what you're looking for.

There's also a section in the DocuSign Developer Center around Embedding functionality:  https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign