# Docusign Embedded Sender with Read Only

Tags: docusignapi

Similar to [Preview tags with docusign API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583819/preview-tags-with-docusign-api) we have the need to let users preview a document before sending it out.

We also need to not let them change the values on the document, just see the populated doc/envelope. 
If there are data problems in the document, that requires fixes on our UI. 
Due to the complexity of the documents, the mappings of our tabs is a one-way operation, and non-signature/initial tabs are read-only.

The [API Explorer](https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=Envelopes&tags=EnvelopeViews&operations=createSender) doesn't provide any options outside of `accountId` and `envelopeId`. Are there additional options available on [this endpoint](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createSender/)?

Barring that, what else can we do to enable envelope preview without editing?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the sender to view the envelope and accept or reject it as is, I'd recommend adding the sender as the first signer, and directing them to a signer view.

First, you'll want to enable 'show initial values' so that all data appears on the envelope regardless of who has taken action. To do so, log in to the web console and navigate to Go to Admin > Sending Settings > Check `When an envelope is sent, write the initial value of the field for all recipients`

If you place an Approve and Decline button for them, they will have the binary choice to accept the envelope. Neither button actually 'burns in' anything to the envelope, so the completed PDF will not be altered.

Note that clicking a Decline button voids the envelope: If you have another workflow in place to modify the envelope prior to it hitting the primary recipient, you may not want to use a Decline button.

Comment: YIKES that'll eat through our DS Envelope limits quickly. Thanks for the heads-up on the  `When an envelope is sent, write the initial value of the field for all recipients` option though, seeing what that can do with the https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=Envelopes&tags=EnvelopeDocuments&operations=get endpoint.

Also updating Tab Values is a good idea.

Comment: True, if you're concerned about a high rate of voided envelopes and the primary issue is bad data populating, you might want to build out a landing page in your app that displays a summary of all the field data you're going to be pushing through. The sender can scan through that to confirm values are correct, and if they are, advance to the point where the envelope is generated. You can then go through the sender-as-first-signer process if necessary, so they can confirm everything is visually acceptable before the customer receives it.